# Без запятых, с одной или обособляем?

Tags: пунктуация

> Получается, что нам представили истории из жизни вот этих, конкретно
>   взятых ряженых.

Вопрос к *вот этих, конкретно взятых*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Получается, что нам представили истории из жизни вот этих, конкретно взятых ряженых.**

Это лучший вариант. Хотя здесь пояснительные отношения (раскрытие значения местоимения *этих*), но они обычно оформляются и читаются как однородные.

Comment: Ок! Ок! Ок! (один ОК, вполне достаточный, не принимается сайтом...)  (((